# How to bind Json data returned by a asynchronous call to a knockout observableArray correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I am trying to get a json object by an ajax call, and put it into a knockout observable.

```
var self = this;
this.arnVal = ko.observableArray([]);

var promise = $.getJSON('../../url/to/my/api');

promise.done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         console.log(data["metricValues"]);                
         self.arnVal().push(data["metricValues"]);
         console.log(self.arnVal());                                     
      });
```

The expected values are getting printed correctly by the console logs inside the `promise.done()` function call. That is, the data is in the correct Array format expected by the Oracle Jet component I am binding it with.

This code is in a Knockout component javascript file, which I am using in a HTML file somewhere else as a part of a Knockout component.
In the HTML file of the component, I am using `arnVal` to populate a Oracle Jet chart.

But the chart never gets populated with the updated `arnVal` data as obtained from the `getJSON` call.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the extra parens from `self.arnVal().push(...)`.

```
self.arnVal.push(data["metricValues"]);
```

Currently the parens are unboxing the observable array and pushing the new item to the underlying javascript array. This bypasses knockout's event triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parenthesis here:

```
self.arnVal().push(data["metricValues"]);
         //^^ here
```

See the spec: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

> var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray();    // Initially an empty array
>   myObservableArray.push('Some value');              // Adds the value and notifies observers

The reason is `self.arnVal` is an observable array while `self.arnVal()` is a simple array (which does not have notification capabilities).